# end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Tags: w3c-validation

please help me, I can't figure it out.

> Line 1011, column 2: end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

I added extra `</div>` but the problem still remain.

Comment: some div open, not closed

Comment: I understand that Selvan but which one ? I use wordpress and I add a extra </div> at the end of footer.php but prob still remain. any idea

Comment: use html tidy see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307178/any-tools-to-find-missing-html-tags

Comment: We need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the element before the /div. I had an issue with a map id="" and I had to close the /map element before closing the div to work.